# How to resolve 504 Gateway Timeout and WebSockets errors with Nginx and Express app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, nginx, socket.io

When I run my express app locally, there are no issues whatsoever, but since I've placed it on an AWS EC2 instance running an Nginx web server, there are a few problems whenever I visit the designated domain.

Whenever I go to the domain, it displays a 504 Gateway Timeout for the main.css file that is being served from the public directory.  Not sure if it's relevant, but I am using Jade templates with Express, and sass files are being compiled at runtime to the public/css directory.

Here's the request headers:
GET /css/main.css HTTP/1.1
Host: dispatch.nucleus.technology
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Referer: http://dispatch.nucleus.technology/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

There also seems to be a websocket error:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://dispatch.nucleus.technology/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=W0qJNlmaVdFbKoeBAAAA' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

I've since fixed the css problem, and it seems that running the app as root solves it, but I'm not sure why - if anyone has some insight regarding that it would be very helpful.

As for the websocket error, I'm still receiving that despite running the app as root.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to the nginx config should get rid of the websocket error:

```
location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    ...
```